# Non-literal type cannot be used in a constant expression (C++)

Tags: c++, constants, constexpr

Here is the definition of the class.

```
Class Type {
  public: 
    constexpr Type (std::string label, const std::set<int>& ids) : label_(label), ids_(ids) {}

  private:
    const std::string label_;
    const std::set<int>& ids_;
}
```

I want to define some const objects so that we can use as the enums. For example:

```
const Type A = {"type_a", {1, 2}};
const Type B = {"type_b", {3}};
```

But I got the following error

```
Non-literal type std::set<int> cannot be used in a constant expression
```

Any idea for how to initial the const object correctly? Suggestions for changing the definition of class are also welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you're trying to use [C++20 features](https://wandbox.org/permlink/AeP4TFE4q0MSsv1v) here (try changing the C++ level and re-running the example).  What compiler and command line switches are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is to create a `const` object like this

```
const Type A = {"type_a", {1, 2}};
```

i.e. an object that cannot be changed once it is initialized, then you merely need to remove `constexpr` from the constructor.

Comment: Then I will get the following error: 
```Non-constexpr constructor 'Type' cannot be used in a constant expression```

Comment: Is this declaration inside a constexpr function?

Answer (score 0):

Simply because you can't create strings at compile time, think about it first, strings most of the time allocate memory. So what will you do about this memory allocation during compile time? You have to provide some compile time allocations, like **pmr** in C++20. By the way, some containers like **std::array**( take a look at this https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/array) can be used in **compile-time** contexts since they are simple enough to be constructed during compilation. Remember that the memory allocated at compile time must be released at the end of the compilation.

And also I think this question may help you a little bit better to comprehend what we have talked about it here.
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/272265/c20-compile-time-string-utility